# Filtering out double quotes from a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have this function right here that takes a string array and is supposed to add everything except some characters to a `List`.

```
public static void cleanUp(string[] results)
{
     List<string> text = new List<string>();
     for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
     {
         string key = results.ElementAt(i);
         if (key != "\",\"" || key != "\"{\"" || key != "\"}\"" || key != "\":\"")
         {
             text.Add(key);
         }
     }
}
```

In the results array there are elements that look like this `,` and `:` and `}` etc... Why is my `if` statement not filtering out the special characters.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: side note : dont use `ElementAt(i)`, use the indexer `results[i]`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use ElementAt(i)?

Comment: ElementAt is used when you have a collection that does not have indexer. when you have a indexer you can directly access the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the or's to && will be a good start!

```
if (key != "," && key != "{" && key != "}" && key != ":")
```

Comment: I see, I wasn't even thinking about that, originally I had == instead of != that's why it was or

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this (*use [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method*):

```
List<string> text = results.Where(key => !key.Contains(',') &&
                    !key.Contains('{') && !key.Contains('}') &&
                    !key.Contains(':')).ToList();
```

`text` is a `List` of strings that has not that special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AND (&&) operator instead of OR (||).  Since you are using || , one of them always matches, and returns true.  Hence, the key gets added.